# How to add the value of keys in an array to a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Hi my dictionary is looking like this

`{'A': [3, 4, 7], 'B': [4, 9, 9], 'C': [3, 4, 5], 'D': [2, 2, 6], 'E': [6, 7, 9], 'F': [2, 4, 5]}`

How would i add the values in the array (numbers) (they already are in integer form) so that it would write the total in the array. After this, how would i sort the dictionary so the lowest total numbers go first?

I need it to be sorted, because the user will input data to go into these arrays.

Comment: Please make the code as simple as possible as i am a beginner thank you.

Comment: This isn't a free code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @somebrick If you try it yourself, can't get it right, show in the question you have tried something, better chances people here would try and help you out.

Comment: See [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question is ambiguous. Are you adding the values of each array in the dictionary together and making a new dictionary that uses those as values? Dictionaries are by definition unsorted, so what do you mean by wanting to sort it? Do you mean you want an `OrderedDict`, or do you want e.g. the smallest sum to be associated with `'A'`?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Ok, the 3 inputs would correspond chronologically to the keys, for example the first 3 inputs would be for key 'A', and would be up to 'F'. I want to order the keys+values based on the values and want to extract the lowest 2 from the dictionary

Comment: You literally cannot order a dictionary, it has no order. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'b': 2, 'a': 1}` evaluates to `True`. So what do you mean by ordering the keys and values? Why do you need to order the dictionary before extracting the smallest 2 values?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To sum the values, you can loop over the data using `.items()`, will return the key with its associated value at each iteration:

```
s = {'A': [3, 4, 7], 'B': [4, 9, 9], 'C': [3, 4, 5], 'D': [2, 2, 6], 'E': [6, 7, 9], 'F': [2, 4, 5]}
new_dict = {}
for a, b in s.items():
   new_dict[a] = sum(b) #here, using sum function to get the total of all elements
```

Dictionaries are unsorted, however, you can keep the data in this format:

```
final_data = sorted(new_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1])
final_output = final_data[2:]
print(final_output)
```

Comment: Without using the import function, how else could i extract the key+values from the dictionary based on the total in the array?

Comment: @somebrick please see my recent edit.

Comment: works @Ajax1234 , how would i dict.pop the first and second indexes in the dictionary?

Comment: @somebrick Do you mean you want to remove the first two values from `final_data`?

Comment: @somebrick you need to write a clear, concise question stating what you want to begin with, instead of continually adding additional requirements to the question. If this works for your original question, you should accept it and open a new question for any follow-up.

Comment: yes @Ajax1234   ty

Comment: wait there wouldnt be a way to still keep it as a dictionary? so just delete the key and the corresponding values? and also can someone help me append a value to a particular key? @Ajax1234

Comment: @somebrick Python dictionaries are unsorted, so there is no way to keep it as a dictionary.

Comment: @Ajax1234 would there be a way to remove the numbers by checking the value of all the keys and deletingthe lowest?

Comment: @somebrick Yes. What numbers are you referring two?

Comment: the numbers in the array after each key, so A:[14], B:[22],etc

Comment: @somebrick Do you just want to delete the lowest value in the array?

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want, with an explanation below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6


def main():
    nums = {'A': [3, 4, 7], 'B': [4, 9, 9], 'C': [3, 4, 5], 'D': [2, 2, 6], 'E': [6, 7, 9], 'F': [2, 4, 5]}

    for key in nums.keys():
        nums[key] = sum(nums[key])

    print(nums)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So what we do here is loop over the keys in your dict then re-assign that key to be equal to the sum of it's elements. You can't sort a dict, so there is no sorting involved here. Why do you need it sorted anyway?

Comment: See edited post, sorry for being vague the values will be inputted, so you cannot use the if statement